# Retrieve special character in php send via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, special-characters, send

I am using ajax jquery to send data  to php, 
as data I am sending one url as string from ajax that contains special character i.e "&"
So I'm not getting full url i.e. my data it retrieved until '&' only rest id ignored and not displayed.

Below is my code for ajax and php:

```
dummytest.php

$temp=$_POST['address'];
echo $temp;
```

test.html
(ajax to send data )

```
    var send="http//192..../oracle/master.php?result=2&table=1"
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "dummytest.php",
        dataType: "text",
        data: send,
        success: onSuccess,
        error: onError
         });
```

I'm sending data "send" i.e one url as string data
but I'm receiving it until  "&" only in my php i.e.

```
http//192..../oracle/master.php?result=2
```

Can any one tell me how can I get my full data/url ?

Comment: Try using the `%26` in place of the `&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the URL as the whole body of the POST request, while on the PHP side you are expecting to find it in the `address` parameter. You should change `send` on the Javascript side to

```
var send = { address: 'http://...' }
```

and jQuery will take care of encoding it in the body of the request.

Comment: hurray i have done thnk u soooooo much :)))))))) i was not aware that we can  use var directly in this way also

Answer (score 0):

Use $(selector).serialize() method.
The serialize() method creates a URL encoded text string by serializing form values.